# How to capture CTRL+X from a ULC KeyTyped char in Java

Tags: java, applet, uitextfield, keyevent

I am using an old **ULC Text Field** (`com.ulcjava.base.client.UITextField`).
It has a `fireKeyTypedULC` method to override. But it has 2 parameters, one is a char other one is an int.

```
@Override
public void fireKeyTypedULC(char arg0, int arg1) ...
```

If I press <kbd>CTRL+X</kbd>, then the char will be a strange question mark icon. If I press <kbd>CTRL+F</kbd>, or with whatever character from the keyboard, it will be again a question mark:
[image]

I cannot handle if I pressed <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>F</kbd> with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> with this stupid character, because if it converts to int to check with `KeyEvent.VK_X` or `KeyEvent.VK_F` (or with <kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>f</kbd>) it will be always 24, which is the `KeyEvent.VK_FINAL`.

So, how could I handle this old useless ULC thingy?

Comment: *"I am using an old **ULC Text Field**"* You write that like we should have any idea what it is. Link to the Java Docs for this component,

Comment: https://ulc.canoo.com/developerzone/doc/ULCCore/7.0.5/apidoc/com/ulcjava/base/application/ULCTextField.html
here it is, it was just 2 seconds

Comment: It took you just a week and two seconds to post information that should have been included in the initial post? (golf clap..)